# error when trying to create new column from two columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which I have two columns(**A** and **B**) and I want one new column **C** which gives me a date starting from the second date of the **B** column

```
A       B           C
1     20170112     20170211
3     20170211     20170315
5     20170315     20170413
9     20170413     20170516
12    20170516
```

last value in column **C** can be zero or null.

I am trying this by this code

```
  ab = ab %>% group_by(A) %>% mutate(C = B[-1])
```

but it gives me error

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Column `C` must be length 13
>   (the group size) or one, not 12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dplyr::lead` is designed specifically for this.

```
df %>%
  mutate(C = lead(B, default = 0))
```