# case_when() not working: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr, tidyverse

**When I run the code below I get this error:**

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Column `den` must be length 2
>   (the group size) or one, not 20000

**Here are my sample data and code:**

```
mydata<-structure(list(condition = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", 
    "C", "D", "E"), r_condition = c(-0.753941712419928, 0.18796391661835, 
    1.07774993391177, 0.141452804751733, -1.67697957194689, -0.730021740287756, 
    0.30088191760836, 0.820982130392851, 0.20992883143208, -1.75797911497123
    ), den_a = c(-1106.36423037457, -1106.36423037457, -1106.36423037457, 
    -1106.36423037457, -1106.36423037457, -1106.36423037457, -1106.36423037457, 
    -1106.36423037457, -1106.36423037457, -1106.36423037457), den_b = c(1013.85560135413, 
    1013.85560135413, 1013.85560135413, 1013.85560135413, 1013.85560135413, 
    1013.85560135413, 1013.85560135413, 1013.85560135413, 1013.85560135413, 
    1013.85560135413), den_c = c(4340.91752722743, 4340.91752722743, 
    4340.91752722743, 4340.91752722743, 4340.91752722743, 4340.91752722743, 
    4340.91752722743, 4340.91752722743, 4340.91752722743, 4340.91752722743
    ), den_d = c(1078.95631612632, 1078.95631612632, 1078.95631612632, 
    1078.95631612632, 1078.95631612632, 1078.95631612632, 1078.95631612632, 
    1078.95631612632, 1078.95631612632, 1078.95631612632), den_e = c(-6530.58467431366, 
    -6530.58467431366, -6530.58467431366, -6530.58467431366, -6530.58467431366, 
    -6530.58467431366, -6530.58467431366, -6530.58467431366, -6530.58467431366, 
    -6530.58467431366)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("grouped_df", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "condition", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
        c(0L, 5L), c(1L, 6L), c(2L, 7L), c(3L, 8L), c(4L, 9L)), group_sizes = c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), biggest_group_size = 2L, labels = structure(list(
        condition = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L), class = "data.frame", vars = "condition", drop = TRUE))

mydata%>% mutate(den = case_when (
       mydata$condition=="E" ~ mydata$den_e, 
       mydata$condition=="D" ~ mydata$den_d,
       mydata$condition=="C" ~ mydata$den_c, 
       mydata$condition=="B" ~ mydata$den_b,
       mydata$condition=="A" ~ mydata$den_a))
```

Similar question have been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803746/mutate-usage-length-of-column-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49357087/error-when-trying-to-create-new-column-from-two-columns) but none of these involve `case_when`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: inside dplyr you do not use `mydata$condition` but just `condition` and `den` instead of `mydata$den`. That is where your error is coming from.

Comment: Thanks, @phiver.  But when I don't use mydata$condition inside `dplyr ` I get an empty column `den`. Any solution?

Comment: remove all references to `mydata$` and your code will run fine. At least in the example data given

Comment: Thanks @phiver. Just let me update the question. Removing all references to `mydata$`  gives an empty column `den`.

Comment: @Krantz I just copy-and-pasted then removed all instances of `mydata` from `case_when`, like @phiver suggests. The `den` column is there and has values.

Comment: Thank you, everybody. Removing all references to mydata$ and restarting R studio solved the problem. I will update the question to make it more helpful for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried restarting your R session? Because for me it seems to work using the default `dplyr` notation as suggested by phiver.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydata<-structure(list(condition = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), r_condition = c(-0.753941712419928, 0.18796391661835, 1.07774993391177, 0.141452804751733, -1.67697957194689, -0.730021740287756, 0.30088191760836, 0.820982130392851, 0.20992883143208, -1.75797911497123), den_a = c(-1106.36423037457, -1106.36423037457, -1106.36423037457, -1106.36423037457, -1106.36423037457, -1106.36423037457, -1106.36423037457, -1106.36423037457, -1106.36423037457, -1106.36423037457), den_b = c(1013.85560135413, 1013.85560135413, 1013.85560135413, 1013.85560135413, 1013.85560135413, 1013.85560135413, 1013.85560135413, 1013.85560135413, 1013.85560135413, 1013.85560135413), den_c = c(4340.91752722743, 4340.91752722743, 4340.91752722743, 4340.91752722743, 4340.91752722743, 4340.91752722743, 4340.91752722743, 4340.91752722743, 4340.91752722743, 4340.91752722743), den_d = c(1078.95631612632, 1078.95631612632, 1078.95631612632, 1078.95631612632, 1078.95631612632, 1078.95631612632, 1078.95631612632, 1078.95631612632, 1078.95631612632, 1078.95631612632), den_e = c(-6530.58467431366, -6530.58467431366, -6530.58467431366, -6530.58467431366, -6530.58467431366, -6530.58467431366, -6530.58467431366, -6530.58467431366, -6530.58467431366, -6530.58467431366)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "condition", drop = TRUE, indices = list(c(0L, 5L), c(1L, 6L), c(2L, 7L), c(3L, 8L), c(4L, 9L)), group_sizes = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), biggest_group_size = 2L, labels = structure(list(condition = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame", vars = "condition", drop = TRUE))

x <- mydata%>% mutate(den = case_when (
  condition=="D" ~ den_d,
  condition=="C" ~ den_c, 
  condition=="E" ~ den_e, 
  condition=="B" ~ den_b,
  condition=="A" ~ den_a))

x
#> # A tibble: 10 x 8
#> # Groups:   condition [5]
#>    condition r_condition  den_a den_b den_c den_d  den_e    den
#>    <chr>           <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 A              -0.754 -1106. 1014. 4341. 1079. -6531. -1106.
#>  2 B               0.188 -1106. 1014. 4341. 1079. -6531.  1014.
#>  3 C               1.08  -1106. 1014. 4341. 1079. -6531.  4341.
#>  4 D               0.141 -1106. 1014. 4341. 1079. -6531.  1079.
#>  5 E              -1.68  -1106. 1014. 4341. 1079. -6531. -6531.
#>  6 A              -0.730 -1106. 1014. 4341. 1079. -6531. -1106.
#>  7 B               0.301 -1106. 1014. 4341. 1079. -6531.  1014.
#>  8 C               0.821 -1106. 1014. 4341. 1079. -6531.  4341.
#>  9 D               0.210 -1106. 1014. 4341. 1079. -6531.  1079.
#> 10 E              -1.76  -1106. 1014. 4341. 1079. -6531. -6531.
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You have just a few mistakes, with this code it works excellent:

```
mydata <- mydata%>% mutate(den = case_when (
  condition=="E" ~ den_e, 
  condition=="D" ~ den_d,
  condition=="C" ~ den_c, 
  condition=="B" ~ den_b,
  condition=="A" ~ den_a))
```